# Communicating from tab to pop up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webcam, face-api

What's the best way to communicate between a pop up and a window  from chrome.tabs.create?

I have a webcam that is using face-api to detect and count smiles. I then load its index.html in a new tab. This is because I wanna constantly track my face, and when previously loaded in a pop up, it stops as soon as the pop up is closed. I want to create a pop up that when the icon is clicked, the number of smiles will show. Creating a new tab with it will make sure that even if I navigate away from the tabs, or close my pop up, it will still detect faces, and when I click the icon pop up, numbers will still be updated.

So how can I get the values (smile count) from the new window tab, into the pop up?

In background.js :

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL('index.html'),
    active: true
  });
```

index.js:

```
function startVideo() {   navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
    err => console.error(err)   ); } video.addEventListener("playing", () => {   const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);   document.body.append(canvas); 
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height };   faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);

  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
      .withFaceLandmarks()
```

Comment: Sounds like chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for rec! But i'm not sure even how to send a message of the smile count from the index, to the pop up, do I used chrome.extension.connect?

Comment: If you want to show the number under the icon then use chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText in index.js. Otherwise you can use a) messaging to and from the background script to keep the data there or b) [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between the popup and index.js - the popup should send the message first or c) the standard DOM things like BroadcastChannel API.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah THANK U SO MUCH!!! it works now! :)